# How do I make this into a table and sort it alphabeticaly

Tags: php

This is a piece of my php script where the database it mirrored into a webpage.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "" . $row["id"]. "" . $row["student"]. "" . $row["subject"]."".    $row["grade"]. "<br></div>";
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: We need to see your query

Answer (score 0):

So sort it alphabetically, it needs to go back to your query.

To do this you need to do your normal query and add `ORDER BY whatever_field_you_want_to_set_as_alphabetical ASC` at the end of it. Example:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY name ASC
```

That sorts out the alphabetical issue.

To put it into a table, you need to first check if there are results.

If there are, then create your table and make sure for every row you create a new row in the table.

```
<?php if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>
      <td>ID</td>
      <td>Student</td>
      <td>Subject</td>
    </th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['student'];?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['subject'];?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
      }
    ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
<?php 
  } else {
    echo "0 Results";
  }
?>
```